# Is it possible to declare a function that accepts an array of superclass instances and returns the most specific subclass type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing a Typescript declarations file for my Javascript package.

My library has a function that accepts an array of superclass elements and returns the superclass.

```
function x(args: SuperClass[]): SuperClass
```

I would like to modify the return type of the method so that it returns the type of the most specific subclass element.

```
function x(args: SuperClass[]): TypeOfMostSpecificArg(args)
```

For Example

```
interface A {}
interface B extends A {}
interface C extends B {}
let a: A, b: B, c: C
x([]) // should have return type A
x([a, b, a]) // should have return type B
x([a, b, c]) // should have return type C
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How could you know the returned type at compile time. You'll only know it at runtime, and it will depend on the elements in the array. And even then, you won't even know at runtime, since interfaces don't exist at runtime. They're a compile-only concept. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have the opposite problem: at runtime you don't know anything about interfaces.  *Classes* have constructors, which exist at runtime, so you might be able to implement this for constructed objects (some kind of mutual `instanceof` check against the `constructor` property of each object).

Comment: Also, in those particular examples, `A`, `B`, and `C` are identical.  You should add properties to them if you want `C` to be more specific than `A`.

Comment: Finally, what do you want if `D extends A` and you're given an array containing a `B` and `D`?  Or a `C` and a `D`?

Comment: I've added additional context in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997777/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-function-that-accepts-superclasses-of-a-given-type. I thought that it might be possible, in some cases, to infer element types at compile time. I never considered the specificity of sibling/cousin classes when asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Using TS3.1 in the following:)

This answer is so full of caveats that I feel weird even posting it.  Plus I don't really think I understand your use case.  But the type juggling involved in locating the most specific type in a list has piqued my curiosity.  So here we are!

The following could *only possibly work* if the objects you pass to `x` contain at least one element that is an `instanceof` the constructor for every single other value passed.  That means the class hierarchy has no forks in it (or at least none in the list of things you pass to `x`) and that it is an actual class hierarchy using prototypical inheritance.

Here goes:

```
type NotExtendsAll<T, U> = U extends any ? [T] extends [U] ? never : unknown : never;
type AbsorbUnion<T> = [T] extends [infer U] ? U extends any ? 
  NotExtendsAll<U, T> extends never ? U : never : never : never;
type Absorb<T extends any[]> = AbsorbUnion<{ [K in keyof T]: [T[K]] }[number]>[0];
function x<T extends any[]>(...args: T): Absorb<T> extends never ? undefined : Absorb<T>;
function x(...args: any[]): any {
    return args.find(a => (args.every(b => a instanceof b.constructor)));
}
```

The explanation is a bit involved as it uses a lot of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), especially [distributed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) ones which allows you to inspect union constituents.  The effect is that `Absorb<>` takes an array (or [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple)) type and returns the element which is a subtype of all the other elements, if there is one... otherwise it becomes the bottom type [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never).

In the `x` function I'm also using rest parameters instead of an array because it helps [infer tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) for the passed-in parameters.

Let's see if it works:

```
class A { a: string = "a" }
class B extends A { b: string = "b" }
class C extends B { c: string = "c" }
let a = new A();
let b = new B();
let c = new C();

const aaa = x(a, a, a); // type is A, returns a at runtime
const aba = x(a, b, a); // type is B, returns b at runtime
const abc = x(a, b, c); // type is C, returns c at runtime
```

Looks right, I think.

Now, this doesn't work:

```
const none = x(); // type is never, returns undefined at runtime
```

I know you wanted it to be `A`, but you're not handing it any parameters.  How can it return a value of type `A` when it doesn't have one?  Oh well, we'll assume there's a value named `a` defined in an outer scope.  You can modify the above to make a zero-parameter `x()` work:

```
function otherX<T extends A[]>(...args: T): Absorb<T> extends never ? A : Absorb<T>;
function otherX(...args: A[]): A {
    return args.find(z => (args.every(b => z instanceof b.constructor))) || a;
}

const none = otherX(); // type is A, returns a at runtime
const otherAba = otherX(a, b, a); // type is B, returns B at runtime
const otherAbc = otherX(a, b, c); // type is C, returns C at runtime
```

Here are some caveats... if you use hierarchies with forks:

```
class D extends A { d: string = "d" }
let d = new D();
const whoops = x(a, b, c, d); // type is undefined, returns undefined at runtime
const alsoWhoops = otherX(b, c, d); // type is A, returns a at runtime
```

If you use non-class instances:

```
const huh = x("a","b","c"); // type is supposedly string, returns undefined at runtime
```

And probably other craziness can happen also.  But that's as close as I can get.  Hope that helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer... I'll have to reread it a few times to make sense of those conditional types. I added additional context in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997777/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-function-that-accepts-superclasses-of-a-given-type.