# Is it possible to declare a function that accepts superclasses of a given type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing [type declarations](https://github.com/lusakasa/sqorn/pull/45/files) for a Javascript library.

I have an interface that is generic on type T. It has a function with an argument that should have type (T | subclass(T) | superclass(T)).

The interface currently looks like the following:

```
interface Query<T> {
  extend(arg: T): T
}
```

As is, Query.extend only accepts T and subclasses of T. How do I add superclasses of T?

**Context:**

[Sqorn Postgres](https://sqorn.org) is an immutable SQL Query Builder with a fluent interface. Its API is based on SQL and features methods like `from()`, `insert()`, `limit()`, etc.

The root query building object has all methods available to it, but as you chain methods, you constrain the query type and fewer methods become available. For example, `sq.insert().having()` will throw a type error because  `sq.insert()` returned an `InsertBuilder` and Insert Queries don't have a `having` clause.

For composability, you can chain method `extend(...queries: AnyBuilder[])` to create a new query from existing queries.

`sq.from('book').extend(sq.where({ id: 1 }), sq.return('name'))`

The types in the method call above are:

```
SelectInsertUpdateDeleteBuilder.extend(
  SelectUpdateDeleteBuilder,
  SelectInsertUpdateDeleteBuilder
)
```

I'd like to add type safety to `extend()` such that if T is the current query builder type, only queries of type T, superclasses of T, and subclasses of T are accepted.

This would, for example, prevent you from extending an Insert Query with methods that only make sense in a Select Query, e.g.

```
sq.insert().extend(sq.limit()) // should throw type error
```

The types in the method call above are:

```
InsertBuilder.extend(SelectBuilder)
```

Comment: The current definitions form npm  for this library are not valid syntactically  :(

Comment: I'm adding typings now. The typings on npm are ancient. You can find the typings I'm working on at https://github.com/lusakasa/sqorn/pull/45/files

Comment: I got the definitions from your branch .. but I don't see the problem. Your first example works, and in your second example I get a type error. What is not working ?

Comment: It is only incidental if the current implementation works for the examples. The correct logic is what I described in the question, but I don't know how to implement the correct logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can make it so that `Query<T>.extend()` only takes parameters that are either assignable to `T` or those that `T` is assignable to.  That is, either a supertype or a subtype.  It uses (as these things often do) [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types):

```
interface Query<T> {
  extend<U extends (T extends U ? unknown : T)>(x: U): U;
}
```

Let's try it:

```
class A { a: string = "a" }
class B extends A { b: string = "b" }
class C extends B { c: string = "c" }

class D extends A { d: string = "d" }
class E { e: string = "e" }

declare let a: A;
declare let b: B;
declare let c: C;
declare let d: D;
declare let e: E;

declare let qb: Query<B>;
qb.extend(a); // okay, B extends A
qb.extend(b); // okay, B extends B
qb.extend(c); // okay, C extends B
qb.extend(d); // error, D not assignable to B
qb.extend(e); // error, E not assignable to B
qb.extend(Math.random() < 0.5 ? a : e); // okay, B extends A | E
```

Looks reasonable to me.  Hope that's useful to you.  Good luck!

---

UPDATE: combining this with [my answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52996943/2887218) about accepting a number of arguments and returning "the most specific one", with all the caveats and craziness from that question, gives you:

```
type NotExtendsAll<T, U> = (U extends any ? [T] extends [U] ? never : unknown : never)
type AbsorbUnion<T> = [T] extends [infer U] ? U extends any ?
  NotExtendsAll<U, T> extends never ? U : never : never : never
type Absorb<T extends any[]> = AbsorbUnion<{ [K in keyof T]: [T[K]] }[number]>[0];

type AsArray<T> = [T] extends [any[]] ? T : never;    
interface Query<T> {
  extend<U extends AsArray<{ [K in keyof U]: T extends U[K] ? unknown : T }>>(
  ...x: U
  ): Absorb<U> extends never ? T : Absorb<U>;
}
```

Basically what I'm doing there is requiring `U` to be an array or tuple of types where each type is either a subtype or supertype of `T`, and it returns the type of the narrowest argument, or just `T` if there is no narrowest argument (zero arguments, or multiple arguments in a forked class hierarchy).

All the above tests give the same results, and now you can also do this:

```
qb.extend(a, a, a); // okay, returns type A
qb.extend(b, a, b, b, a); // okay, returns type B 
qb.extend(a, b, c, b, a); // okay, returns type C
qb.extend(); // okay, returns type B
```

Not sure about the implementation of `Query`; hopefully you can handle that.

Good luck again!

Comment: that is clever.

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully! My library's extend() function actually accepts an array of queries so now the only potentially unsafe situation is if two arguments have incompatible types, e.g. sq.extend(sq.insert(), sq.limit()). Would you recommend limiting extend to exactly one argument to preserve type safety? Or is there conditional type magic that can account for this? I'm still trying to parse your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995749/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-function-that-accepts-an-array-of-superclass-instanc?noredirect=1#comment92896737_52995749

Comment: I finally realized the type requirements for the extend(...args) method: all arguments must be of the same lineage with no forks and the return type is the most specific argument type. I don't know if it is possible to declare this function with a variadic array argument, but it should be possible to enumerate arities up to a fixed number.

Comment: One issue with this solution is that the return type becomes the argument type. Is it possible to make the return type the more specific of the base type and argument type?

Comment: Updated with stuff from the other question

Comment: Thanks. I added additional followup in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016538/given-this-typesafe-method-accepting-one-argument-can-you-generalize-it-to-n-ar